# inherit is not Defined

Tags: javascript

I'm studying a javascript book, and i have this example

```
 var p = {
// x and y are regular read-write data properties. x: 1.0,
    y: 1.0,
// r is a read-write accessor property with getter and setter. // Don't forget to put a comma after accessor methods.
    get r() {
        return Math.sqrt(this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y);
    }, set r(newvalue) {
        var oldvalue = Math.sqrt(this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y);
        var ratio = newvalue / oldvalue;
        this.x *= ratio;
        this.y *= ratio;
    },
    // theta is a read-only accessor property with getter only.
    get theta() {
        return Math.atan2(this.y, this.x);
    } };

var q = inherit(p); // Create a new object that inherits getters and setters
q.x = 0; q.y = 0; // Create q's own data properties
console.log(q.r); // And use the inherited accessor properties console.log(q.theta);
```

But I have this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: inherit is not defined`

Comment: You are missing contructor `inherit`, suppose it is defined before this code in your book !

Comment: Thanks, but I don't fund this constructor

Comment: If you don't at least tell us *which* book that is, we will not be able to help you finding it. It might however make sense if `inherit = Object.create`

Comment: Is it this book and function? https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-definitive-guide-david-flanagan-6th/chapter-6/creating-a-new-object-that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking up this code on internet suggests you might be reading O'Reilly's 'JavaScript: the Definitive Guide'. If so, the code for `inherit()` is given in example 6-1:
See here: https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-definitive-guide-david-flanagan-6th/chapter-6/creating-a-new-object-that

Answer (score 1):

To add to Mchl's answer (I had the same problem, but couldn't follow the link in his answer), the following is the code for the inherit function as in Javascript The Definitive Guide's example 6.1:

```
// inherit() returns a newly created object that inherits properties from the
// prototype object p.  It uses the ECMAScript 5 function Object.create() if
// it is defined, and otherwise falls back to an older technique.
function inherit(p) {
    if (p == null) throw TypeError(); // p must be a non-null object
    if (Object.create)                // If Object.create() is defined...
        return Object.create(p);      //    then just use it.
    var t = typeof p;                 // Otherwise do some more type checking
    if (t !== "object" && t !== "function") throw TypeError();
    function f() {};                  // Define a dummy constructor function.
    f.prototype = p;                  // Set its prototype property to p.
    return new f();                   // Use f() to create an "heir" of p.
```

Answer (score 1):

Straight to the point, you've missed the code on page 119 (see references at the end), on which inherit function is defined. It seems that you are treating 'inherit' function as a "native function" and it is not. So as has been said, you need to "construct" that function before inicialization - so you don't get `Uncaught ReferenceError: inherit is not defined`.

That error is telling you the clue: "inherit is not defined", so the first step is to look up where is this function defined. If it is not defined yet and you want to use it, you just need to define it as suggested bellow or with the specific instructions you need to play. If you're learning, it is very important to understand what erros are teeling you.

So, before calling 'inherit' function add the following code as suggested by the book:

```js
// inherit() returns a newly created object that inherits properties from the
// prototype object p. It uses the ECMAScript 5 function Object.create() if
// it is defined, and otherwise falls back to an older technique.
function inherit(p) {
     if (p == null) throw TypeError(); // p must be a non-null object
      if (Object.create) // If Object.create() is defined...
        return Object.create(p); // then just use it.
     
     var t = typeof p; // Otherwise do some more type checking
     
     if (t !== "object" && t !== "function") throw TypeError();
       function f() {}; // Define a dummy constructor function.
        f.prototype = p; // Set its prototype property to p.
        return new f(); // Use f() to create an "heir" of p.
}
```

***Example 6-1**. Creating a new object that inherits from a prototype.* JavaScript: The Definitive Guide, by David Flanagan (O'Reilly). Copyright 2011 David Flanagan, 978-0-596-80552-4. 6th Edition.